# A characterization of convexity for functions with vectors as domain.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function.

By $df(w)$ I denote the Frechet derivative of $f$ at $w$

Prove that $$f \:\text{is convex} \Leftrightarrow \forall(a,b)\in R^n\times R^n,df(b)(b-a)\geq df(a)(b-a)$$

I managed to prove the direct implication quite simply by considering the real function of the variable $t$ : $f(a+t(b-a))$.

I'm stuck with the converse. I tried to prove the following function of $t$: $(1-t)f(a)+tf(b)-f((1-t)a+tb)$ was negative. It has $0$ for value at $0$ and $1$.

What should I do next?

By the way, can someone recommend me a book that covers the subject of differentiation of vector-functions and convexity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A differentiable function of one variable is convex **iff** the derivative is non-decreasing.

A function $f$ is convex **iff** for all $x,h$, the restriction $t \mapsto f(x+th)$ is convex.

Combining gives:

A differentiable function $f$ is convex **iff** for all $x,h$, the restriction $t \mapsto f(x+th)$ is convex **iff** for all $x,h$, the derivative $(f \circ \phi_{x,h})'$ is non-decreasing, where $\phi_{x,h}(t) = x+th$.

Since $(f \circ \phi_{x,h})'(t) = Df(\phi(x+th)h$, by taking $x=a, h=b-a$ and $t=0$ and $t=1$ respectively, we see that $Df(b)(b-a) \ge Df(a)(b-a)$.

To obtain the other direction, suppose $Df(b)(b-a) \ge Df(a)(b-a)$ for all $a,b$. Then let $a=x+sh, b=x+th$, with $s\le t$, then we see that $(f \circ \phi_{x,h})'(t) \ge (f \circ \phi_{x,h})'(s)$, that is, $(f \circ \phi_{x,h})'$ is non-decreasing.